# find all urls prefixed with something specific flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to construct a test environment for a series of blueprints in my flask application. The directory structure looks a bit like this:

```
run.py
app/
  blueprints/
    __init__.py
    bp.py
    bp2.py
    bp3.py
  __init__.py
  views.py
```

**init**.py within the blueprints directory looks like this:

```
from app import app
from bp import bp
from bp2 import bp2

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix('/generate'))
app.register_blueprint(bp2, url_prefix('/generate'))
app.register_blueprint(bp3, url_prefix('/do_something_else'))
```

Now, I want to launch a test system that does something like this (pseudocode):

```
for every url that starts with /generate:
  j = json.load(that_url())
  with open('fixture.json', 'r') as fixture:
    if j == json.load(fixture):
      app.logger.info('TEST PASSED')
```

How would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this with regular expressions?
something like:

**assuming the end of the url is the end of the line...

```
u=re.compile('/generate(...)\n'')
r=u.findall(datatosearch)
for l in r:
    j = json.load(l)
    #Add the rest of your operations here....
```